# How to read data in Java from a Python Struck.pack

Tags: java, python

I am using Java UDP datagrampacket to receive a python packet which contains a Struct.pack string. How could I unpack it in Java?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the packet as byte[] array in Java, you can use [java.io.java.io.ByteArrayInputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html) to create an InputStream from it which can be wrapped by [java.io.DataInputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) which provides methods to read several simple datatypes.

Be aware that DataInputStream works with big endian. If you use little endian some byte juggling will be necessary for multi-byte integer types.